# Single line expression/formula for matching the string from comma separated list

Tags: regex, vba, substring, instr

I have following string which is a comma separated list

```
Dim str1, str2

str1="C_adminToolsChartsOnFormsManager,C_adminToolsFormDesignerCopyFormDesign,C_adminToolsManageLocationsAccessSubSystem,C_adminToolsManageLocationsAddLocation,C_adminToolsManageLocationsCopyLocation"
str2="C_adminToolsFormDesigner"
```

I want to search `str2` in `str1` with exact match. `C_adminToolsFormDesigner` should **not** match with `C_adminToolsFormDesignerCopyFormDesign`.

I have used below single expression but it always returns true. It should do the exact match and should return false.

```
IIF(InStr(str1,str2),"True","False")
```

Can anyone help me in writing the single line expression?

Comment: What your programming language? VBA?

Comment: Yes. I want expression in VBA

Comment: OK, tagged it with `vba`.

Comment: So what is `var` and the semicolon? If it is VBA, shouldn't you declare your variables with `Dim`?

Comment: my bad. Actually we are using Logi tool which supports VBA expression which runtime change the expression with actual value. I have added var just for the explanation. Please read it as Dim

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the commas, like so:

```
result = IIf(InStr("," & str1 & ",", "," & str2 & ","), "True", "False")
```

NB: I'm not sure why you would want True and False as String data type. It seems more natural to produce a Boolean value:

```
result = InStr("," & str1 & ",", "," & str2 & ",") > 0
```